# What is the value being passed into this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

Forgive me if this is a stupid question but I am not sure where to look. I have this code that compiles fine:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var parserResult = CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);

    parserResult.WithParsed<Options>(options => OnSuccessfulParse(options));
    parserResult.WithNotParsed<Options>(errs =>
    {
        var helpText = HelpText.AutoBuild(parserResult, h =>
        {
            return HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(parserResult, h);
        }, e =>
        {
            return e;
        });
        Console.WriteLine(helpText);
        ReturnErrorCode = ErrorCode.CommandLineArguments;
    });

    return (int)ReturnErrorCode;
}
```

My query has to do with this line of code:

```
parserResult.WithParsed<Options>(options => OnSuccessfulParse(options));
```

I understand that with a [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) the value on the *left* of the `=>` is the *value* and value on the *right* is the *expression*.

What exactly is `options`? Why does it compile? It works absolutely fine. But what is it?

I don't know if this helps:

[image: Definition of WithParsed]

I might be barking up the wrong tree with my understanding of this. I admit I am struggling with the concept. Any explanation appreciated.

I see several questions but I can't explain it in my situation.

## Update

`OnSuccessfulParse` declaration is:

```
private static void OnSuccessfulParse(Options options)
```

The `WithParsed` code is provided [here](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/blob/master/src/CommandLine/ParserResultExtensions.cs)

Comment: Well presumably `WithParsed<T>` accepts an `Action<T>` or maybe a `Func<T, T>` (we don't know what `OnSuccessfulParse` is, which doesn't help). But what value that gets given is part of the library - have you looked at the code and the documentation for that library? This isn't a general C# language question - it's specific to the library.

Comment: `options` is instance of class `Options`, which, as I understand, represents successfully parsed command line options. So if library suceeded to parse command line options to the given class (`Options`) - it will invoke a callback. That callback is what you pass to `WithParsed`. So your callback will be invoked, and then `OnSuccessfulParse` method will be invoked (by your code).

Comment: my understanding is that `options` is i/p parameter to delegate represented by lambda expression.

Comment: The underlying framework/library you are using creates/manages that `Options` object and at some point passes it into your lambda.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside `OnSuccessfulParse` and check the value of `options` there?

Comment: @Rafalon I know what type of object it is as I have defined the `Options` class.

Comment: @Evk I have tweaked my question with a link to the `WithParsed` method that does use one of these actions.

Comment: I never mentioned *check the **type** of `options`*, I said *check the **value** of `options`* (as per *What is the **value** being passed [...]*)

Comment: @Rafalon When inside the `OnSuccessfulParse` method my `options` parameter is a correct set of parsed command line arguments.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes, here: https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda expression is the delegate of type `Action<Options>`. It is a callback from the parser into your code to inform you that the parse has been successful, and pass you `Options` object obtained as the result of the parse.

As far as `options` goes, it's just a name that you picked for the parameter to be passed into `OnSuccessfulParse` method. It is completely unnecessary here - this method group equivalent call will compile and run just the same:

```
parserResult.WithParsed<Options>(OnSuccessfulParse);
```

Here is the definition of `WithParsed<T>` method from [github project](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/blob/master/src/CommandLine/ParserResultExtensions.cs):

```
public static ParserResult<T> WithParsed<T>(this ParserResult<T> result, Action<T> action)
{
    var parsed = result as Parsed<T>;
    if (parsed != null) {
        action(parsed.Value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This method is rather straightforward: it takes parse result, tries casting it to a successful parse, and if the cast is valid, calls a delegate that you supply. The `WithNotParsed<T>` method casts to unsuccessful `NotParsed<T>` result, and makes a call if the cast is valid.

Comment: Right! So, `options` is the `parsed.Value` object. And `parsed` is of type `Parsed<T>`. Because `action` is the `OnSuccessfulParse ` function call with that as the parameter.

Comment: I am going to accept this as the answer because it specifically addressed my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

That's a C# (.Net) way of representing function blocks.
Essentially an `Action<Type>` is an invocable type that roughly means `pass an instance of Type in and execute the block`.

E.g. we can write

```
public void Do(){
  this.CallStuff(s => Console.WriteLine(s)); // or you can use a method group and do this.CallStuff(Console.WriteLine);
}

public void CallStuff(Action<string> action){
  var @string = "fancy!";
  action(@string);
}
```

In this case the `s` type is `string`.

In your example there is a type called `Options` defined somewhere and it is passed into an action.

Additionally, if you look at decompiled code, anonymous method blocks passed to actions are compiled as static anonymous types inside your class (because c# does not support dynamic code blocks, like, for example, obj-c does).

Another thing to look into are `Func<out type>` -> these are essentially the same as `Action<>` except the LAST type in the generic definition is the type they return.

*UPD*
@elgonzo raises a good point - `Action<>` and `Func<>` are actually just delegates; meaning that you can define a real method and pass it along as an Action or Func and then no anonymous static class will be compiled.

However in practice you will see that a lot of code defines those inline, and then the in-line code block needs to reside within a method somewhere, so the compiler puts it into the statis anonymous class.

Comment: To clarify: you can see "s" or "options" as a variable name here. It doenst matter if you call it "options", "myVar" or just (most unreadable) "a".

Comment: Your explanation with regard to Action<T> is misleading. To be precise, Action<...> and Func<...> are delegates, not static anonymous types. It just so happens that in your example instances of the Action<T> delegate references an anonymous method. Since they are delegates, Action<...> and Func <...> delegates can also reference "normal" named instance/static methods.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is options?

`options` is i/p parameter to delegate represented by lambda expression

> Why does it compile?

Simply because it adheres all syntactical and semantic rules of compiler ;) Like `(x)=>x+1` is lambda expression to represent `Func<int,int>` (there can be another delegate to match same signature as well)

If your method expects `Func<int,int>` as parameter and argument passed is `(x)=>x+1` then compiler infers this as x of type int. Compiled IL code would be equivalent to passing instance of delegate as an argument to method. Like :

`call((x)=>x+1)` will be compiled to `call(new Func<int,int>(myMethod))` where call method definition is :

```
void Call(Func<int,int> someparam) {}
```

> But what is it?

I think above response should have addressed this query.